# how to start the main page content after the fixed header so that the hyperlink section do not overlap with header?

Tags: html, css

I wrote this HTML page, but whenever I'm clicking on the hyperlinked text, the linked section overlaps with the static header.

I wanted all linked sections to appear after the header. How to do it also the dimensions of the iframe are different for each section?

Is there any what to start the main content from a fixed point on the page? So that all the hyperlinked sections start from that point only?

HTML code:

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <style>

    #main2
    { padding-bottom:0px;
      margin-top: 0px}

    #header2
    { background:#3A332D;
      height:50px;
      margin-bottom:30px;
      position:fixed;
      top: 247px}

    #header3
    { background:#3A332D;
      height:250px;
      margin-bottom:30px;
      position:fixed;
      top: 0px}

    #menubar2
    { height:47px;
      width:1500px;
      margin:10px auto 10px 0}

    #menubar3                                                                                                                                              { height:47px;                                                                                                                                           width:1500px;                                                                                                                                          margin:10px auto 10px 0}

    #menubar3                                                                                                                                              { height:47px;                                                                                                                                           width:1500px;                                                                                                                                          margin:10px auto 10px 0}

    ul#menu2
    { float:left;
      margin:0 auto 0 100px;
      position:fixed;
      top: 243px}

    ul#menu3
    { float:left;
      margin:0 auto 0 600px;
      position:fixed;
      top: 165px}

    ul#menu2 li
    { float:left;
      padding:0 0 0 15px;
      list-style:none;
      margin:2px 2px 0 0;
      background:#635B53 url(tab.png) no-repeat 0 0}

    ul#menu2 li a
    { font:normal 100% 'trebuchet ms', sans-serif;
      display:block;
      float:left;
      height:20px;
      padding:6px 28px 5px 12px;
      text-align:center;
      color:#FFF;
      text-decoration:none;
      background:#635B53 url(tab.png) no-repeat 100% 0}

    ul#menu2 li.tab_selected a
    { height:20px;
      padding:6px 28px 5px 22px}

    ul#menu2 li.selected
    { margin:2px 2px 0 0;
      background:#635B53 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 0 0}

    ul#menu2 li.selected a, ul#menu li.selected a:hover
    { background:#635B53 url(tab_selected.png) no-repeat 100% 0;
      color:#111}

    ul#menu2 li a:hover
    { color:#ECEF01}

    </style>

    <body>

    <div id="main">
          <div id="header2">
            <div id="header3">
             <div id="menubar3">
                <ul id="menu3">
                    <h1 style="font-family:courier;color:white;"><b> RESULTS</b> </h1>
                </ul>
             </div>
            </div>
              <div id="menubar2">
                   <ul id="menu2">
                    <li><a href="#l1">link1</a>
                    <li><a href="#l2">link2</a>
                    <li><a href="#l3">link3</a>
                    <li><a href="#l4">link4</a>
                    <li><a href="#l5">link5</a>
                   </ul>
               </div>
          </div>

    <div><h1><a name="l1"></a>link1</h1></div>
    <div><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" style="height:600px;width:350px;"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div margin= 5px; top= 750;>
    <h1><a name="l2"></a>link2</h1></div>
    <div>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" style="height:350px;width:350px;"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div margin= 5px; top= 750;>
    <h1><a name="l3"></a>link3</h1></div><div>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" style="height:500px;width:350px;"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div margin= 5px; top= 750;>
    <h1><a name="l4"></a>link4</h1></div><div>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" style="height:150px;width:350px;"></iframe>
    </div>

    <div margin= 5px; top= 750;>
    <h1><a name="l5"></a>link5</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/" frameborder="0" style="height:190px;width:800px;"></iframe>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What is happening with the above code:
when I'm clicking on `link2` instead of link-2 coming just below the static header. It's getting merged with the header section:

[image]

How exactly I'm expecting it to come:
[image]

Similarly, when I'm clicking on `link3`, the linked section link-3 also getting merged with the header section (that's why it's appearing partially).
[image]

How exactly I'm expecting it to come:
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you want, from my understanding I have redesigned the HTML page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>
    *,
    *::before,
    *::after {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html {
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
    }

    body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: #3A332D;
        height: 200px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;

        /*If you want the header to be sticky to top

        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        
        */
    }

    .header h2 {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 20px auto;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    ul {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }

    ul li {
        margin: 10px 20px;
        list-style: none;
        background-color: #635B53;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    ul li:hover a {
        color: #ECEF01;
    }

    ul li a {
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .video__wrapper {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .video {
        width: 560px;
        height: 315px;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }

    iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Result</h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#link1">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link2">Link2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link3">Link3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="video__wrapper">
        <div class="video" id="link1">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KsIDRek_Gmc" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="video" id="link2">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KsIDRek_Gmc" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="video" id="link3">
            <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KsIDRek_Gmc" frameborder="0"
                allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture"
                allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But even in this If I'm using [position = sticky], and clicking on the hyperlinked text, the associated section merged (intersect) with the static header (because of that the video section is not fully visible it's half cut). I just wanted the associated linked section to come below the static header. Sorry if I'm not able to explain it with the right terminology.